# MySQL Left join cannot remove duplicates in a single query

Tags: mysql, sql, date, left-join, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables:

products:

```
- id
- name
```

product_images:

```
- id
- image
- product_id
```

I'm doing the following query:

```
SELECT p.*, i.image
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN product_images i
ON p.id = i.product_id`
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

However if a product has a few images, then this product row is duplicated. How can i remove these duplicates, by showing only the 1st match in a pair of `p.id = i.product_id`

Comment: `GROUP BY` should help you in this.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this dataset, simple aggregation should do it:

```
SELECT p.*, min(i.image)
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN product_images i ON p.id = i.product_id
GROUP BY <enumerate all columns from products here>
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT ${limit}
```

If you want more colums from `product_images`, then you can also filter with a correlated subquery; assuming that `product_images` has primary key `id`, that would look like:

```
SELECT p.*, i.image
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN product_images i 
    ON i.id = (SELECT MIN(i1.id) FROM product_images i1 WHERE i1.product_id = p.id)
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT ${limit}
```

Comment: Thanks, in your first example, you wrote: `GROUP BY <enumerate all columns from products>`, what if i have 40 columns? Can i just make `GROUP BY p.*`?

Comment: @AlexanderKim: I don't think that this is valid syntax. And, in general, it is a good practice to enumerate the columns rather than using `*` (for example, this avoids breaking the results of queries when new columns are added to the table).

Comment: @AlexanderKim: that would really depend on your dataset... You would need to test both options and see which performs better.

Answer (score 1):

If `image`'s data type is varchar or int then instead of joining the table `product_images`, join to the MIN of the images of each product:

```
SELECT p.*, i.image
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT product_id, MIN(image) image
  FROM product_images 
  GROUP BY product_id
) i
ON p.id = i.product_id
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT ${limit}
```